# Sending php value to js via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So, I have the following ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: custom.ajax_url, 
    dataType: 'html',
    data: ({ action: 'ajax_call'}),
    success: function(data){    
            jQuery('.container').append(data);// Need changes

});
```

Then my php:

```
function rhmain_tag() {
    // 1. Getting wp tag list:
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order'   => 'DESC'
    );

    $tags = get_tags($args);
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        echo $tag->term_id;
    }

    //2. Getting "another.php" file
    $template_part_path = 'page-parts/another_php';
    get_template_part($template_part_path);

    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_call', 'ajax_call');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_call', 'ajax_call');
```

As you can see, in the php function, there are two separate thing going on.

1. Getting tag list passed onto the js as variable.

   - `echo $tag->term_id;` shows a number like this "16508164981650616502165031650416505165071650116520." So, somehow I need to put comma in between each term id (not sure how) so it looks like this : "16508,16498,16506,16502,16503,16504,16505,16507,16501,16520"
   - Then I need to pass these values to js to be used as a variable (not sure how)
2. `another_php` file is passed onto js (Works fine).

**Questions:**

1. How to do I add "comma" in between the tag term_id?
2. How do I pass these tag values to js?

**EDIT: Using json_encode to pass data**

**PHP**

```
function rhmain_tag() {     
$template_part_path = 'page-parts/another_job';
$return_data['another_job'] = get_template_part($template_part_path);
$return_data['tag_id'] = '16498';
echo json_encode($return_data);
exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_rhmain_tag', 'rhmain_tag');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rhmain_tag', 'rhmain_tag');
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: custom.ajax_url, 
    dataType: 'html',
    data: ({ action: 'ajax_call'}),
    success: function(data){    
            jQuery('.container').append(data.another_php);
            var tag_list = data.tag_id;
});
```

Comment: What is passed to javascript from the ajax call is whatever you `echo` out.

Comment: On the echo you can concatenate a comma `echo $tag->term_id.',';`. Do you want to echo the IDs as well as the template you are appending to `.container`? It sounds like you are intending to use the IDs in jquery, so you probably don't want them appended to `.container`?

Comment: @Tristan. You are exactly right. I want to use the `id` separately from the php file. How do I separate these two different values (`another_php.php` and `id`s). For the `ids`, I am planning to use them in a variable for another function.

Comment: To use them separately either use 2 ajax calls, OR rather than echoing the outputs directly in the php script, use `json_encode()` an array containing the IDs and the another_php, then use them separately in the js.

Comment: I added an edited version in the question using `json_encode`. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `json_encode` to send an array containing both data that you require front end you then need to make the following changes to your ajax function.

1. Change the `dataType` to `json`
2. Access the data as `data.another_php` and `data.tag_id`

The full ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: custom.ajax_url, 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: ({ action: 'ajax_call'}),
    success: function(data){    
        jQuery('.container').append(data.another_php);
        var tag_list = data.tag_id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add the comma in between you could use a variable to store instead of echo'ing immediately. Like this :

```
$args=array(
    'orderby'=>'count',
    'order'=>'DESC'     
);
$tags = get_tags($args);
$tag_list = "";
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_list += $tag->term_id + ",";
}
// Now trim the last comma
$tag_list = rtrim($tag_list, ",");
echo $tag_list;
```

Comment: I used @tristan's answer for the comma issue : `echo $tag->term_id.',';`